# Tumblr image posting getting 404 error

Tags: iphone, tumblr

I am Trying to `post image on Tumbler`

Here I get the Error: `"{"meta":{"status":404,"msg":"Not Found"},"response":[]}"`Any one please help me.

Comment: You should include your code so that we can see how you try to post it.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are not giving any details I can only guess you're making the same mistake I made:

When calling the Tumblr API for a blog you need to have the full blog URL in your REST call:

```
http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/example.tumblr.com/post
```

Or in other words: Include ".tumblr.com" [in the hostname](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#overview).